# Escritura de archivo de texto con longitud fija y variable

Tags: c

No entiendo que es lo que estoy haciendo mal con la escritura de los archivos de texto, ya que me salen muchas advertencias.
Alguno me puede ayudar a saber en que le estoy pifiando?

```
fread(&reg,1,sizeof(info),fp);
while(!feof(fp))
{
    fprintf(fpTextFijo,"%*ld%-*s%-*s%*f\n",SIZE_DNI,reg.dni,SIZE_NAME,reg.name,SIZE_SURNAME,reg.surName,SIZE_AVERAGE,reg.average);
    fprintf(fpTextVar,"%ld|%s|%s|%f\n",reg.dni,reg.name,reg.surName,reg.average);
    fread(&reg,1,sizeof(info),fp);
}


C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: field width specifier '*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 5 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: field width specifier '*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 6 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 7 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: field width specifier '*' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 8 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 9 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|36|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|37|warning: unknown conversion type character '|' in format [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|37|warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 3 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|37|warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 5 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]|
C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\Estructuras de datos\main.c|37|warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta anteponer un `.` en el especificador `*`.

Su correcto uso es: `.*`

Probá modificando tu linea de código de la siguiente manera y varios de tus warnings deberían solucionarse:

```
fprintf(fpTextFijo,"%.*ld%-.*s%-.*s%.*f\n",SIZE_DNI,reg.dni,SIZE_NAME,reg.name,SIZE_SURNAME,reg.surName,SIZE_AVERAGE,reg.average);
```